# assertIn with count

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, python-unittest

What is the most idiomatic (There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it :) ) way to assert that something occurs in iterable instance exactly *count* times? I want to achieve behavior described bellow.

```
checked = 'pum-pum-pata-pum'

#something like this
self.assertIn('pum', checked, count=3) # OK
self.assertIn('pum', checked, count=2) # Error
self.assertIn('pum', checked, count=4) # Error
```

I have this ability with django assertContains but it assert that you have response.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with a list or tuple, my guess is the most idiomatic way would be

```
assert iterable.count(element)==number
```

This also works on strings, including if `element` is not a single character - although, arguably, this doesn't strictly count "that something occurs in a iterable instance exactly count times", since a string's elements are characters.

On generic iterables, you could use list comprehensions or a filter with lambda:

```
assert len([e for e in iterable if e==element]) == number
assert len(filter( lambda e:e==element, iterable)) == number
```

I think the first option is the clearest for most people.

Comment: +1, but you solution doesn't solve problem with string. What do you propose to do with my code sample?

Comment: @kharandziuk The `count` method exists on strings too. I've edited the answer to clarify this.